# What does (%f\n) mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, definition

There's this example that was shown in our class today:

```matlab
age = 20
fprintf("age is"%f\n);
```

What is the purpose of "%f\n"?
I initially thought it was a placeholder for variables.

It should come out as

> age is 20

in the output bar.

If we are using the variable `age`, how can I rewrite this program?

Comment: Since you still have not, please take a [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

The %f is indeed a placeholder for variable output in MATLAB, but this syntax is invalid:

```
age = 20 fprintf("age is"%f\n);
```

What it should be is:

```
age = 20;
fprintf("age is %f\n",age);
```

The \n part is a newline to advance the cursor to the next line.